# Convert object to an array with underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

I'm trying to covert javascript object to an array using Underscore, but I have some problems with understanding Underscore.
I want to covert this:

```
{ key1: value1, key2: value2},{key1: value1, key2: value2}
```

Into this:

```
[value1, value2],[value1, value2]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `_.map` and `_.values` like this

```
var data = [{ key1: 1, key2: 2 }, { key1: 3, key2: 4 }];
console.log(_.map(data, _.values));
# [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ] ]
```

If you fancy generic JavaScript version, you can do

```
console.log(data.map(function(currentObject) {
    return Object.keys(currentObject).map(function(currentKey) {
        return currentObject[currentKey];
    })
}));
# [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're having input as `Array` of Objects and want the result in `Array` of Arrays, then you could just use native javascript to do it

```
var output = input.map(function(obj){ return [obj.key1, obj.key2] });
```